# VS 2010 Project Build only in specific Solution Configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, build, project, solution

Hi everyone out there on StackOverflow; this isn't exactly a coding question like I'm used to having here, but it is definitely confusing for the moment.

I'm fairly sure this is possible but I'm not sure how to accomplish this:

Is there a method of having an individual specific project in a solution only build in specific configurations?  For example, I may want every project to build in Release mode, whereas in debug mode I want all projects except for the one to build.

I feel like this should be a simple property to change, however I'm having a lot of trouble exactly determining where and what that property would be.

Thank you everyone for any and all possible help.

Answer (score 0):

- Where you can choose Release / Debug - press on the arrow down
- choose "Configuration Manager"

you can do exactly what you are looking for there - you can add more configurations as well

Comment: Thank you very much!  I knew it would be something simple, I just couldn't find it.